# Javascript Tesseract without jpg/png/

Tags: javascript, casperjs, tesseract

I try to use Tesseract for the first time. But i got the problem, that my image is not a "normal" image.png or something like this, it is just a link like: "path/to/image.php".

So does anybody know, how i can use Tesseract with this "image" ?

I had the idea, that i can just save this image locally and then get it read by Tesseract, but it does not work to save it via Filestream..

When is do like

```
var foo = "https://website.domain/path/to/image.php";
```

Then my foo is just a [Nodelist object]

So how to do Tesseract with this ?^^

Comment: Maybe you should provide real path to .php

Comment: I just use Javascript in console with CasperJS not on Website =)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can download the image first, then using the "normal" image path.